# Как сделать REPL режим из cmd после завершения скрипта Python?

Tags: python, cmd

Если запускать скрип из IDLE Python, то после его завершения в интерактивном режиме IDLE можно использовать переменные этого скрипта, можно ли как-то добиться подобного из командной строки или из visual studio code, например?

Answer (score 0):

Добавить флаг `-i` при запуске.
CMD `python -i script.py`

Ещё можно использовать

```
import code
...
code.interact(local=locals())
```

или установить модуль ptpython и в коде:

```
from ptpython.repl import embed
...
embed(globals(), locals())
```